# Placing two axis environments relative to each other in TikZ figure

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, horizontal-alignment, vertical-alignment

I am currently making a Ti*k*Z figure containing both standard lines using `\draw` and two different plots, each in their own axis environment. I want to place them all together with the plots placed diagonally relative to each other, as shown in the figure below

[image]

The above figure has been generated using the following code using ShareLaTeX, along with packages `tikz` with and `pgfplots` with

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}

\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\usepackage[active,floats,tightpage]{preview}
    \setlength\PreviewBorder{1em}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}

    % =================== Binding energy graph ========================

   \node [anchor=south west] (nodeEb) at (-0.1,-0.1){};

\node [anchor=south west] (DOS) at (2.2,-0.5){};

    \begin{axis}
     [  % graph position
        at={(nodeEb)},
        ticks = none,
        set layers,
        axis on top,
        axis line style = thick,
        width=7.5cm,
        height=7cm,
        axis lines=center, 
        domain=0:5,
        samples=100,
        xmin=0, xmax=3,
        ymin=0, ymax=8,
        xlabel style={at={(DOS)},anchor=west},
        y label style={at={(axis description cs:-0.1,0.3)},anchor=south},
        xlabel={DOS},
        ylabel={$E_{B}$}
       ]

       % Fermi energy
       \addplot[color=teal, domain=0:5.9,samples=100, name path=fermi]({0.5*(x-4)^(0.5)},{x});

        % Fill under Fermi
       \path[name path=axis] (axis cs:0,3.9) -- (axis cs:0,5.9);
        \addplot [thick, color=teal, fill=teal,]
                fill between[of=fermi and axis,];
    \end{axis}

    \draw [thick,teal] (0,0.5) -- (4,0.5); % Core energy top
    \draw [thick,teal] (0,1.4) -- (3,1.4); % Core energy bottom
    \draw [thick,teal] (0.05,0) -- (0.05,3); % Baseline

    % ======== Kinetic energy graph =========

    \node [anchor=south west] (nodeEk) at (5.7,4.4){}; % Node plot E_k

    % Axis label nodes
    \node (Int) at (7.5,4.22) {};
    \node (Ek) at (5.8,10){};

    % Ek plot
    \begin{axis}
     [  
        at={(nodeEk)},
        ticks = none,
        set layers,
        axis on top,
        axis line style = thick,
        width=5.5cm,
        height=7cm,
        axis lines=center, 
        domain=0:5,
        samples=100,
        xmin=0, xmax=3,
        ymin=0, ymax=8,
        xlabel style={at={(Int)},anchor=west},
        ylabel style={at={(Ek)},anchor=west},
        xlabel={Intensity},
        ylabel={$E_{K}$}
       ]

       % core signals
       \addplot[color=teal,fill=teal, domain=0:4,samples=1000, name path=peak1] ({0.03/pi*(1/(1+4*(x-1))^2)+7/pi*(0.005/(0.005+4*(x-2)^2))},{x});

       % Fermi energy
       \addplot[color=teal, domain=0:7,samples=100, name path=fermi]({0.7*(x-4)^(0.5)/(e^((x-6)/0.1)+1)},{x});

        % Fill under Fermi
       \path[name path=axis] (axis cs:0,3.9) -- (axis cs:0,10);
        \addplot [thick, color=teal, fill=teal,]
                fill between[of=fermi and axis,];
    \end{axis}

    % ======== Supporting lines ==============
    \draw [thick,dashed] (3.1,1.4) -- (9.8,1.4); % Upper core level Eb

    \draw [thick,dashed] (0,4) -- (8,4); % Fermi energy Eb
    \draw [thick] (0,5) -- (3.5,5) -- (5.8,4.53); % E_{Vac}
    \draw [thick,dashed] (8.9,5.9) -- (9.8,5.9); % Upper core level Ek
    \draw [thick,dashed] (5.9,8.55) -- (9.8,8.55); % Fermi energy Ek

    % ======== Arrows =========================

    \draw[thick,<->] (2.2,4.1)--(2.2,4.9); % Surface work function
    \draw [thick,<->] (5.9,4.1) -- (5.9,4.4); % Analyzer work function
    \draw[thick,->] (-0.5,1.7)--(-0.5,0.7); % Binding energy arrow 
    \draw [violet,very thick, decorate, decoration={snake}, ->] (9.2,1.5)--(9.2,5.7); % Photon

    % =========== Text ========================

    \node at (2.5,4.5){$\Phi_{S}$}; % Surface work function
    \node at (6.3,4.22){$\Phi_{A}$}; % Analyzer work function
    \node at (-0.5,4){$E_{F}$}; % E_F Binding energy graph
    \node at (-0.5,5){$E_{V}$}; % Vacuum energy level
    \node at (5.4,8.55){$E_{F}$}; % E_F Kinetic energy graph
    \node at (2.3,3.4){Valence band}; % Valence band
    \node at (4.2,1){Core levels}; % Core levels
    \node at (8.5,2.8){\large $h\nu$}; % Photon
    \node at (2.1,6){\Large \textbf{Sample}}; % Sample text
    \node at (8,9.5){\Large \textbf{Analyzer}}; % Analyzer text

    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Photoemission process}
    \label{fig:photoemission}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

**My problem is:** as I change environment to using MacTeX and Sublime Text 3, the secong graph (Analyzer) insists on being placed at the same origin as the first graph. *in other words, the `at={(nodeEk)}` does not seem to work*.

[image]

Does anyone have a solution to how to place two axis plots displaced relative to each other in the same Ti*k*Z figure?

Any help is kindly appreciated!

Comment: I pasted your code and it works just fine ([code](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/18408fe5d018ec80b4ce94ee71e064ef), [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Zm42.png)) using TeXlive 2017 on Linux.

Comment: your code also works fine with miktex, recent version.

Comment: Another solution would be to use `xshift` and `yshift` options to obtain the right positionning. You may put the two `axis` and their associated annotations in separate `scope` environments to ease manipulation

Comment: Your code works fine here as well, which makes it harder to debug. Can you show the `.log` file generated when trying your example on the Mac?

Comment: @TorbjørnT. should be [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=18Fo7MfpCVdCYyssuKODeWSVZBRxBCIbx)

Comment: I note that your MacTeX is a couple of years old, and that you appear to have TikZ version 3.0.0 and `pgfplots` version 1.12. The latest stable versions are 3.0.1a and 1.15, respectively. It could be that whatever the problem is has been fixed in later versions, so that upgrading will fix it.

Comment: Updating to MacTeX 2017 fixed it! Thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the cause is: the OP's TeX distribution is out-of-date.